# is if x <> empty the same as if not isempty(x)

Tags: if-statement, vbscript, is-empty

Are these two snippets equivalent in VBScript?

```
If x <> empty
    'do something
End if
```

```
If not isempty(x)
    'dosomething
End if
```

Context:

I want to rewrite a condition from

```
If ((Not IsEmpty( Var ) ) And  ( Var <> "" ) )    Then
```

to the less verbose

```
If Var <> Empty And Var <> ""  Then
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; the operator approach would fail for a variant typed *as object*

```
dim woof
set woof = nothing

msgbox isempty(woof) '// ok -> false

msgbox woof = empty  '// object reference not set error
```

(Because the `=` approach would attempt to read the value of the default property of the object)

Comment: as it happens, this is in an elseif following an if isobject condition, so in my case this is not a problem. This answers my question perfectly though, so thank you!